# How to run python sqldf module inside static function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqldf

I have this code which works fine:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqldf
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': ['Jhon1', 'Jhon2', 'Jhon3']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': ['Doe1', 'Doe2', 'Doe3']})
sql_query = '''
select * from df1
left join df2
on df1.col1=df2.col1
'''
result_df = sqldf.run(sql_query)
result_df
```

However when I wrap it inside class function like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqldf
class MyAmazingClass:
    def static_function():
        df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': ['Jhon1', 'Jhon2', 'Jhon3']})
        df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': ['Doe1', 'Doe2', 'Doe3']})
        sql_query = '''
        select * from df1
        left join df2
        on df1.col1=df2.col1
        '''
        result_df = sqldf.run(sql_query)
        return result_df
df = MyAmazingClass.static_function()
df
```

I am getting this error:

> AttributeError: module '**main**' has no attribute 'df2'

How to make this code work in class function?

Comment: A possible patch, non an actual solution: use `global df1, df2` at the beginning of your frunction

Comment: Agree on "possible patch, non an actual solution", but it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandasql.sqldf` instead:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf
class MyAmaizingClass:
    def static_function():
        df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': ['Jhon1', 'Jhon2', 'Jhon3']})
        df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': ['Doe1', 'Doe2', 'Doe3']})
        sql_query = '''
        select * from df1
        left join df2
        on df1.col1=df2.col1
        '''
        result_df = sqldf(sql_query)
        return result_df
MyAmaizingClass.static_function()
```

Output:

```
   col1   col2  col1  col2
0     1  Jhon1     1  Doe1
1     2  Jhon2     2  Doe2
2     3  Jhon3     3  Doe3
```